# Using commands as arguments

Tags: luatex

I have several commands I want to override. Code for these commands is almost the same, so I decided to use the prop module. But when I use #1 #...n for commands I get an error, that it is missing `\begin{document}`. Here is a part of the code I wrote for this. Yes, I can override chapter, section, sub...section, paragraph commands one each, but in my opinion my code will be more readable with iteration and less than if I overridden each command separately. The second question, how can I use my code within the second argument of `\prop_map_function:NN`, i.e. without creating a special command for this, because I do not want to create a special command for this \iterate. If it is impossible to do an iteration without creating commands, please help me solve at least the first problem. Thanks very much everybody for the help.

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N {\g_sections_prop}
\prop_gput:Nnn{\g_sections_prop}{\chapter}{h1}
\prop_gput:Nnn{\g_sections_prop}{\section}{h2}
\prop_gput:Nnn{\g_sections_prop}{\subsection}{h3}
\prop_gput:Nnn{\g_sections_prop}{\subsubsection}{h4}
\prop_gput:Nnn{\g_sections_prop}{\paragraph}{h5}
\protected\def\iterate#1#2{
\ifdef{#1}{
\let#1=c@#1
\renewcommand{#1}[1]{
\tagstructbegin{tag=#2}
\tagmcbegin{tag=#2}
c@#1{##1}
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
}
}
}
\prop_map_function:NN{\g_sections_prop}{\iterate}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: By convention, `N`-type arguments are not braced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `\prop_gput:Nnn` is stringified, so when you use it is not a control sequence any longer.

A proper implementation might be

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_kozlovskiy_sections_prop
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_kozlovskiy_sections_prop
 {
  chapter=h1,
  section=h2,
  subsection=h3,
  subsubsection=h4,
  paragraph=h5,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__kozlovskiy_iterate:nn
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cT { #1 }
   {
    \cs_set_eq:cc { orig@#1 } { #1 }
    \cs_gset_protected:cpn { #1 } ##1
     {
      \tagstructbegin{tag=#2}
      \use:c { orig@#1 } { ##1 }
      \tagmcend
      \tagstructend
     }
   }
 }

\prop_map_function:NN \g_kozlovskiy_sections_prop \__kozlovskiy_iterate:nn

\ExplSyntaxOff

\show\chapter

\stop
```

You can avoid defining the iteration command using `\prop_map_inline:Nn`

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_kozlovskiy_sections_prop
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_kozlovskiy_sections_prop
 {
  chapter=h1,
  section=h2,
  subsection=h3,
  subsubsection=h4,
  paragraph=h5,
 }
\prop_map_inline:Nn \g_kozlovskiy_sections_prop
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cT { #1 }
   {
    \cs_set_eq:cc { orig@#1 } { #1 }
    \cs_gset_protected:cpn { #1 } ##1
     {
      \tagstructbegin{tag=#2}
      \use:c { orig@#1 } { ##1 }
      \tagmcend
      \tagstructend
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\show\chapter

\stop
```

The output on the console is

```
> \chapter=\protected\long macro:
#1->\tagstructbegin {tag=h1}\use:c {orig@chapter}{#1}\tagmcend \tagstructend .
```

If the class is not `book` but `article`, `\chapter` would not be defined.

You can avoid `\use:c` with some trickery:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_kozlovskiy_sections_prop
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_kozlovskiy_sections_prop
 {
  chapter=h1,
  section=h2,
  subsection=h3,
  subsubsection=h4,
  paragraph=h5,
 }
\prop_map_inline:Nn \g_kozlovskiy_sections_prop
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cT { #1 }
   {
    \cs_set_eq:cc { orig@#1 } { #1 }
    \cs_gset_protected:cpx { #1 } ##1
     {
      \exp_not:N \tagstructbegin{tag=#2}
      \exp_not:c { orig@#1 } { ##1 }
      \exp_not:N \tagmcend
      \exp_not:N \tagstructend
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\show\chapter

\stop
```

With this we get

```latex
> \chapter=\protected\long macro:
#1->\tagstructbegin {tag=h1}\orig@chapter {#1}\tagmcend \tagstructend .
```